# Passing multiple observer values as method parameters

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
this.httpService.createSomething(
    this.userObserver.getFullName().subscribe(),
    this.userObserver.getPhoneNumber().subscribe(),
    this.userObserver.getEmailAddress().subscribe(),
).subscribe(() => console.log('Well done'));
```

The above will not work but it was the best example I could give to describe what i'm trying to achieve

I could subscribe to each of the userObserver methods and assign the output value to a component property and pass the component property values into the createSomething() method but that seems very messy

It's nice that in an Angular template I can do `(this.userObserver.getFullName()|async)` to view it's output value and i'd like to that inside method parameters

Is that at all possible?

Comment: you probably need to use a switchMap on a combineLatest that is wrapping getFullName, getPhoneAddress and getEmailAddress. The switch map would subscribe to createSomething once the combineLatest resulting observable emits

Answer (score 1):

well there are different ways of approaching the problem. One way would be to use the `zipWith` pipe operator that subscribes to a source observable and combines it with the values of any number of observables inputs. The `zipWith` operator is RxJS 8's replacement for the deprecated `zip` operator. You could do something similar like:

```
import { zipWith } from 'rxjs';

private createResult() {
   this.userObservable.getFullName().pipe(
      zipWith(
        this.userObservable.getPhoneNumber(),
        this.userObservable.getEmailAddress()
      ),
      map(([fullName, phoneNumber, emailAddress]) => this.httpService.createSomething(fullName, phoneNumber, emailAddress))
    ).subscribe((result) => console.log(result))
  }
```

That approach has the benefit that your are not nesting multiple subscriptions inside each other which may lead to unintended side-effects.